# Pedido de token angular

Tags: angular, http, get, request

Como colocar meu token de Autorização no meu pedido http (GET). Este é o meu código atual:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Guilherme';
    url = 'https://URL.com'
    token = 'b7ff1...';

    constructor(http: Http) {       
        let stream = http.get(this.url, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.token),
        }).subscribe();
    }
}
```

> webpack: Compiled successfully. ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(28,36): error TS2345: Argument of type 'headers: HttpHeaders;}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'
>
> Types of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o seu problema esteja acontecendo pois você está importando `http` de um módulo (`@angular/http`) enquanto que o `Headers` vem de outro módulo (`@angular/common/http`).

Por indicação da equipe do Angular (devido à remoção futura do módulo @angular/http) você deve importar ambos do módulo `@angular/common/http`, isso deverá resolver o seu problema.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Guilherme';
    url = 'https://URL.com'
    token = 'b7ff1...';

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        let stream = http.get(this.url, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.token),
        }).subscribe();
    }
}
```